# Changing raster color range in GRASS NVIZ

Tags: grass-gis, nviz

I'm trying to create a 3d map in GRASS NVIZ from a GDEM (raster) and the range of colors that show the height of the terrain are very ugly.

How I can change them?

For example, I would like the low levels in green and yellow high altitudes, simulating aridity with increasing altitude.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same thing as with raster: modify or change the color table (simple ascii files, [grass/branches/releasebranch_6_4/lib/gis/colors](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/branches/releasebranch_6_4/lib/gis/colors) )

- [r.colors](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/r.colors.html)
- [Color tables in GRASS GIS – using the command line](http://pvanb.wordpress.com/2010/10/01/color-tables-in-grass-gis-using-the-command-line/)
- [GRASS GIS color maps](https://sites.google.com/site/hamishbowman/grass_color_maps)
- [Palettes from GRASS](http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/grass/index.html)