# Exporting from NVIZ?

Tags: qgis, 3d, nviz

I need to export a 3d model made from a DEM with a satellite photo draped over it. I'm using qGIS 2.8.2 and NVIZ, and am having a few problems.

1) How do I get a full colour image draped over a DEM in NVIZ? When I import the original (it's a jpeg but I can convert it) into GRASS GIS it separates it into RGBA channels, and I can only overlay one of those over the DEM.

Any suggestion on how to overlay the optical image?

2) I've got a working DEM with a single channel image overlaid, but i go to export using one of the three options from the 'save image as' menu (PPM image, TIFF image, or Max resolution PPM), nothing happens.

Does anyone know how to get these functions to work?

Or if they're working, where do they save the files/what do are they named by default?

I'm ultimately doing this so I can import a 3D scene into Blender; if anyone's done this in a more straightforward way I'd be happy to have your suggestions.

Comment: GRASS GIS is not QGIS and the NVIZ processing version is very limited compared to the GRASS GIS version: look at [How to get custom colormap onto 3D NVIZ in QGIS GRASS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/76238) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Clip the image to the size of the DEM then export the terrain only to Blender then apply the clipped image as a texture in Blender?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very straightforward way to load GIS data directly into Blender with this [plugin](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS) by Domlysz. The wiki shows how to install and use it. I've had the best success using projected datasets rather than lat/lon, only as I find it easier to match metres to Blender units when manipulating the data in 3D.

Blender should also ignore the separate channels of your image.